# 2D Animation Rendered View is green

Tags: rendering, animation, grease-pencil, 2d, effects

Alot of the 2D ANimation tutorials I'm watching apply this sick Rim Effect that creates a cast shadow/highlight on the desired objects (Grease pencil strokes), however, I can't see it being applied. If I go to rendered view, I can see the modifiers and effects are working however, everything turns Green! Please help!

Blender file (4.4mb) is here: https://pasteall.org/blend/81b468f8fd21484ea2ca7985bfce8c4f

Cycles and Evee have the same issue (GPU compute, CPU makes no difference)
World Colour is white, surface set to background

My rig:
Intel Xeon E3 1270 3.30Ghz
18 GB Ram
MSI RX 570 4GB

[image: Blender screenshot showing above problem]

Answer (score 1):

Materials have been overridden by vertex color

Open Vertex Paint edit mode, then Paint -> Reset Vertex Color

[image]